# var $ = this.jQuery cannot understand

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function () {
    var $ = this.jQuery;

    this.myExample = function () {};
}());
```

Can you tell me what this line means:

```
var $ = this.jQuery;
```

I am new to javascript

Comment: See [Basic Plugin Creation](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), especially *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, every function is invoked on an object that can be accessed with `this`.  What `this` is depends on the way the function is called, and defaults to `window`:

```
obj1.func(); // "this" inside "func" will be "obj1"
func.call(obj2); // "this" inside "func" will be "obj2"
func(); // "this" will default to "window"
```

In your case, you are using the third way: `(function(){...})()` calls the function "unbound", and `this` will default to the global `window` object.

```
var $ = this.jQuery;
```

Will now bind the value of `window.jQuery` to the variable name `$`, which happens to be a valid identifier name in JavaScript.  As the jQuery library provides all its functionality in a global function `window.jQuery`, this is a convenient way to access it using the shorter name `$`:

```
$("a").click();
```

---

To experiment with `this` in JavaScript, try out the following in your browser's JavaScript console:

```
function alertThis() { alert(this); }
var obj = {method: alertThis};

alertThis(); // will show something similar to [object Window], as "this" is "window"
alertThis.call("Foobar") // will show "Foobar"
obj.method(); // will show something similar to [object Object], as "this" is "obj"
```

Comment: obj1.func(); // "this" inside "func" will be "obj1"
func.call(obj2); // "this" inside "func" will be "obj2"
func(); // "this" will default to "window" can u provide example for that if u can

Answer (score 2):

since it is an [IIFE](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression), `this` refers to the window object inside the scope of the function(since it may not be using strict mode), so we are creating a local variable called `$` which refers to the global jQuery variable for easy access.

But it can be simplified as

```
(function ($) {
    this.myExample = function () {};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: It is also good to mention that `$` is a valid identifier in Javascript, unlike in many (most?) languages where the dollar symbol cannot be part of an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

`var $ = this.jQuery;`  means `$` as `this.jQuery;` in `(function () {}());` scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is a variable, you can say that `$` will have the value of `this.jQuery`.

```
var $ = this.jQuery;
```

var is a short for variable, $ is the name of that variable, and the value of it is on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

That line is is mapping $ to this.jQuery. Essentially so when calling a function that uses this.jQuery object, $ can be used instead., for example you would use $.somefunction() instead of this.jQuery.somefunction()

Answer (score 1):

The self executing function that encloses those two lines creates the scope. "this" would be the document. If jQuery is loaded then there is this.jQuery so $ becomes this documents jQuery.